# Pagination not working correctly with Twig

Tags: wordpress, pagination, twig, timber

I'm using Twig inside WordPress within the Timber plugin and I have basically followed the layout they have used for pagination [here](https://github.com/timber/starter-theme/blob/master/templates/index.twig).

It displays fine and everything, but it appears the arguments aren't working correctly for this bit:

```
{% include 'partials/pagination.twig' with { pagination: posts.pagination({show_all: false, mid_size: 2, end_size: 1}) } %}
```

No matter what I set those arguments to it outputs *every* page; so if I have 10 pages it will print out all 10 page numbers; I don't want this, I'm trying to restrict it to 5.

What is wrong here?

Comment: The recordset contains 10 pages worth of records, but you only want to show 5 pages? Why don't you limit the recordset then?

Comment: @DarkBee No, you're misunderstanding. I only want to show 5 pages at one time. If Google has 1000 pages of results, they don't show all 1000 links at once. :)

Comment: @DarkBee Unless you mean limit the recordset for each particular page so it moves up in the recordset to show the correct page numbers.

Comment: No it's confusing cause you are talking about pages. So you have 10 items which you want to display on 2 pages with 5 items each correct?

Comment: See [here](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/pagination/#what-if-i-m-not-using-the-default-query) to change your query accordingly

Comment: @DarkBee No, no, I just want standard pagination - if I have 100 _results_ and want to display 10 per page, this means I will have 10 _pages_, however, like all sites that use pagaination do, they don't display links to all 10 pages at once, they will usually display 5 or so; default WordPress displays previous page/next page for example.

Comment: Ok - Now I understand, give some minutes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use the default `pagination` template, you can go full custom

```
{% set pages_to_show = 5 %}
{% set current = posts.pagination.current %}
{% set max = current + (pages_to_show - 1) %}
{% if max > posts.pagination.total %}
    {% set current = posts.pagination.total - (pages_to_show - 1)  %}
    {% set max = posts.pagination.total %}
{% endif %}


<div class="tool-pagination">
    {% if posts.pagination.prev %}
        <a href="{{posts.pagination.prev.link}}" class="prev {{posts.pagination.prev.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Prev</a>
    {% endif %}    
    <ul class="pages">
        {% for i in current..max %}
            <li>
                {% if posts.pagination.pages[i].link %}
                    <a href="{{posts.pagination.pages[i].link}}" class="{{posts.pagination.pages[i].class}}">{{posts.pagination.pages[i].title}}</a>
                {% else %}
                    <span class="{{posts.pagination.pages[i].class}}">{{posts.pagination.pages[i].title}}</span>
                {% endif %}
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
        {% if posts.pagination.next %}
            <a href="{{posts.pagination.next.link}}" class="next {{posts.pagination.next.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Next</a>
        {% endif %}     
    </ul>
</div>
```

[lightweight demo](https://twigfiddle.com/vdl6p6)

---

*do not this is just a small example of how you could solve this*